# Relational table - is JSON recommended?

Tags: sql, json, rdbms, relational

Trying to implement a relational table that links a user to it's favorite books.

So I have a table with `book_id` and `user_id`

Sample Table:

```
user 1 favourite 1
user 1 favourite 2
user 1 favourite 3
```

Can't I have something like a JSON array?

```
user 1 [favourite 1, favourite 2, favourite 3] ?
```

Performance-wise is it better to do things like in the first example, or the second?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. It shouldn't have been answered, it should have closed as a duplicate. Or as too broad, since  in practice it depends on so many chaotically-related details & you don't give them or a definition of "best".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first solution is a junction/association table and it is the recommended solution for SQL-based relational databases.  Basically, you have two entities, books and users.  The junction table is a third table that connects them.

SQL provides the functionality for this purpose.  Relational databases provide the mechanisms for optimizing performance -- through indexes, column stores, horizontal partitioning, and fancy algorithms -- that make this work effectively, even for very large databases.

Does this mean that JSON structures are never used?  Absolutely not.  They have their place -- some databases even provide indexing support for them.

However, from the database perspective, JSON structures add additional overhead for extracting values.  They also impede optimization.  So, such an array within a row is not the *first* choice for the data representation.

Answer (score 4):

For straight performance out of a SQL database, the join table is better as per Gordon Linoff's answer.

If you're serialising/deserialising complex objects however it is often more performant to store the object as JSON in a field in a table.

I had a project where I had a fully normalised structure to support an advertising schedule. It worked well until one client created a schedule with 40,000 spots in it. The time to save and load the large advertising schedule versus the small schedules was minutes versus seconds.

I changed the structure to store the object as JSON. The time to serialise then save and deserialise then load the large advertising schedule went from minutes to seconds.